# scrolling inside a timeline that is made with html & css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am working on a web project where I have to draw a timeline with rows and information (comparable with a [Gantt chart](http://dlhsoft.com/GanttChartLibrary/2.0/Documentation/Screenshots/GanttChartView.png)). Basically the following is important:

- The user can scroll in time (to the left or right).
- The timeline can be scrolled vertically (scrolling through the rows).
- The name of the row is always visible on the row itself.

To clear things op I've created the following *masterpiece art*:
[image: timeline]

We can see the timeline with the rows in red, the name of the row is on the left (orange) and items on the rows are colored blue. So scrolling the timeline to the right will result in something like this:

[image: timeline scrolled]

The names are still on the same position as we can see and that is exactly the question I have:

**What is the best practice of keeping items on the same horizontal position within a container that is horizontally and vertically scrollable?** Of course when vertically scrolling through the rows, the orange blocks should also scroll along.

### But hey! What did you try so far?

I tried a couple of things but could not find the perfect solution:

#### 1) Changing the left property

I tried changing the css `left` property of the orange blocks with javascript while horizontally moving (changing the position with [Translate()](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) did not change much). This works well on chrome but on IE (still don't understand why people use it) it is really slow and the position update is clearly visible. If you take the scroll bar and start scrolling like crazy, you can see the orange boxes flying from left to right. Which brought me to the following idea:

#### 2) YOU! get out!

I made a separate container element for the orange boxes and put it outside of the timeline, gave it an absolute position and placed it on top of the timeline so it stays there no matter if the user is scrolling the timeline. Results: No difference in appearance and scrolling to the left and right works perfect because I don't have to set the left position of the orange boxes. **BUT...** This solution may work for scrolling horizontally, but when scrolling vertically, the orange boxes have no clue about the vertical position of the timeline, so disadvantages of this solution are:

- The vertical scroll position of the orange boxes has to be set with javascript.
- Scrolling vertically is a bit laggy on IE (but smoother and less annoying than first solution).
- (minor) The height of both containers has to be the same, which means setting the height (when needed) has to be done twice.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: FYI: This practice is commonly referred to as "freezing" the column. That may help you in your research efforts.

Comment: @MemetOlsen can you provide code to play with for this e.g. jsfiddle, etc.?

Comment: I totally understand why you want some code but that is not possible because 1) The project is for a company which I am working for. 2) The used html, css and javascript on the page is very huge, has (knockoutjs) bindings all over the place and the timeline is connected to an internal service and thus is showing real data. That is why I tried my best to create a drawing of the very simplified version of the relevant core.

Comment: @MemetOlsen a simplified version could help your trouble shooting efforts?

Comment: Actually, I am asking for the best way to achieve what I described. So providing code of something that I am not satisfied with seems a little bit odd for me. I already tried solution 1 & 2 and I need a third one.

Comment: Assuming you meant a `fixed` position in solution 2, maybe you can toggle that to `absolute` when vertically scrolling - so it scrolls naturally and not through javascript. Then when it stops scrolling, reset to `fixed` and record and set the `top` positioning of each box?

Comment: Re: How you generate the page, any problem iterating the rows twice?

Comment: Have you thought about displaying the timeline through an iframe, and using the iframe's scrollbars?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is exactly what you wanted, but I thought I'd post it anyway since it's a little different from your solution no. 2 and might have some advantages.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qsfGJ

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right-column">
    <div class="left-column">
        <div class="label">Label 1</div>
        <div class="label">Label 2</div>
        <div class="label">Label 3</div>
        <div class="label">Label 4</div>
        <div class="label">Label 5</div>
        <div class="label">Label 6</div>
        <div class="label">Label 7</div>
        <div class="label">Label 8</div>
        <div class="label">Label 9</div>
        <div class="label">Label 10</div>
        <div class="label">Label 11</div>
        <div class="label">Label 12</div>
        <div class="label">Label 13</div>
        <div class="label">Label 14</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 1</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 2</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 3</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 4</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 5</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 6</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 7</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 8</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 9</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 10</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 11</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 12</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 13</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-label">Row 14</div>
        <div class="event"></div>
        <div class="event"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scrollable horizontal timeline - CSS3

I was working recently on something similar - stumbled upon this (quite old) question in this era where IE "left the block", and still found this task relatively challenging. Here's my take to a solution using

`position: sticky;`

**Example** - with bonus ruler and bars:

```css
.TL {
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px; /* set as desired */
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #ddd;
}
.TL-scroll {
  width: max-content;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.TL-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  flex: none;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.TL-row--top {
  background: #eee;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.TL-row--top .TL-rowCells {
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa, #aaa 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #aaa, #aaa 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 10px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 6px, 0 14px;
}
.TL-rowName {
  position: sticky;
  flex: 0 0 120px;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}
.TL-rowRuler {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1px;
  background: #f0a;
  /* IMPORTANT use translateX to move the rulers! */
  transform: translateX(161px); /* This will most probably be handled by JS */
}
.TL-rowCells {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.TL-cell {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #0cf;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="TL">

  <div class="TL-scroll">

    <div class="TL-row TL-row--top">
      <div class="TL-rowName"></div>
      <div class="TL-rowRuler"></div>
      <div class="TL-rowCells"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="TL-row">
      <div class="TL-rowName">1 Row name</div>
      <div class="TL-rowRuler"></div>
      <div class="TL-rowCells">
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:50px; margin-left:0px;">50</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:120px; margin-left:40px;">120</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:190px; margin-left:400px;">190</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="TL-row">
      <div class="TL-rowName">Row 2</div>
      <div class="TL-rowRuler"></div>
      <div class="TL-rowCells">
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:300px; margin-left:20px;">300</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:20px; margin-left:100px;">20</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:60px; margin-left:5px;">60</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:100px; margin-left:40px;">100</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:80px; margin-left:0px;">80</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:30px; margin-left:50px;">30</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:60px; margin-left:0px;">60</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="TL-row">
      <div class="TL-rowName">Row 3 name</div>
      <div class="TL-rowRuler"></div>
      <div class="TL-rowCells">
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:200px; margin-left:300px;">200</div>
        <div class="TL-cell" style="width:40px; margin-left:20px;">40</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```